# Limiting access of a GCP Cloud IAM custom role only to a bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-iam

AWS provides a way through its IAM [policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies.html) to limit access from a **particular user/role** to a **specific named resource**.

For example the following permission:

```
    {
      "Sid": "ThirdStatement",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:List*",
        "s3:Get*"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::confidential-data",
        "arn:aws:s3:::confidential-data/*"
      ]
    }
```

will allow all `List*` and `Get*` operations on the `confidential-data` bucket and its contents.

However, I could not find such an option when going through GCP's [custom roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-custom-roles).

Now, I know that for GCS buckets (which is my use case) you can create either [ACLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists) to achieve (more or less?) the same result.

My question is, assuming I create a service account identified by `someone@myaccount-googlecloud.com` and I want this account to have **read/write** permissions to `gs://mybucket-on-google-cloud-storage`, **how should I format the ACL to do this?**

(for the time being, it does not matter to me whatever other permissions are inherited from the organization/folder/project)

Answer (score 2):

From [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/acl#ch-examples):

> Grant the **service account** foo@developer.gserviceaccount.com **WRITE** access to the **bucket** example-bucket:

```
gsutil acl ch -u foo@developer.gserviceaccount.com:W gs://example-bucket
```

> Grant the **service account** foo@developer.gserviceaccount.com **READ** access to the **bucket** example-bucket:

```
gsutil acl ch -u foo@developer.gserviceaccount.com:R gs://example-bucket
```

Answer (score 1):

The format for ACL is as below

```
{
  "bindings":[
    {
      "role": "[IAM_ROLE]",
      "members":[
        "[MEMBER_NAME]"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Please refer to the [Google Docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/using-iam-permissions#storage-add-bucket-iam-python)

e.g.

```
{
 "kind": "storage#policy",
 "resourceId": "projects/_/buckets/bucket_name",
 "version": 1,
 "bindings": [
  {
   "role": "roles/storage.legacyBucketWriter",
   "members": [
    "projectEditor:projectname",
    "projectOwner:projectname"
   ]
  },
  {
   "role": "roles/storage.legacyBucketReader",
   "members": [
    "projectViewer:projectname"
   ]
  }
 ],
 "etag": "CAE="
}
```